# Is there App will hide/show in React Native? Issue with Keyboard listeners being removed when switching apps

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am hiding (animating height) image when keyboard will show and showing it (reseting height to default) again when keyboard will hide.

The issue is that if I start editing (keyboard shows) then I switch apps and return back to this app (on iOS) then the animation inside keyboardWillHide won't run and it seems like both listeners `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` are removed.

Is there a way to reapply those listeners again when user switches back to the app?

Sample code:

```js
const AnimatedImage = ({ uri }) => {

 const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 300;
 const height = new Animated.Value(IMAGE_HEIGHT);

 useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardWillShow = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', (e) => {
      Animated.timing(height, {
        duration: e.duration,
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    });

    const keyboardWillHide = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', (e) => {
      Animated.timing(height, {
        duration: e.duration,
        toValue: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    });

    return () => {
      keyboardWillShow.remove();
      keyboardWillHide.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return <Animated.Image style={[styles.image, { height }]} source={{ uri }} />
}

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

So `@react-native-community/hooks` includes exactly what I needed, it can read the appState `'active', 'background', or (iOS) 'inactive'` and reapply keyboard listeners if app shows again.

```js
import { useAppState } from '@react-native-community/hooks';

...

const appState = useAppState();
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [appState]);
```